# Assigning PDO::FETCH_ASSOC result to a $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have a login page that collects clients mapped a certain user upon login.

```
$query_acct = "select client from app_reports.user_map where user_name = '".$username."'";
$acct = $DB_con->prepare($query_acct);
$acct->execute();
$row_acct = $acct->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row_acct['client'])){
    foreach($row_acct as $r) {
        $client[] = $r['client'];
    }
    $_SESSION['client'] = $client;
}
```

As I understood it, `$_SESSION['client']` should store the array stored in `$client`.
But when I attempted to print it out with:

```
foreach($_SESSION['client'] as $key=>$value){

    // and print out the values
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';

}
```

I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: client
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I'd like to get some advice on how to store an array in a session properly so I can print them out (will be used as a dropdown, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r` the entire `$_SESSION`? I am guessing you don't have any error messages on populating the `$_SESSION['client']`.

Comment: Maybe `$row_acct['client']` is empty

Comment: `print_r($row_acct)` and post its value

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php --  You will not be getting a `$row_acct['client']` set with `fetchAll` you either want a normal `fetch` or to iterate through the `fetchall` result and check if `'client'` is set on each row.

Comment: Other variables stored in $_SESSION work properly?
Are you using "session_start();" before messing with $_SESSION variable?

Comment: I omitted the if (!empty($row_acct['client'])){ } lines and it actually echoes out the result (more than 20 values in fact)..isn't !empty working with fetchAll?

Answer (score 0):

[`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array (possibly an empty one).

Combined with the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` parameter, if the array is not empty, then it will contain an indexed array of associative arrays.

This logically means that `!empty($row_acct['client'])` can never be satisfied.  Alternatively, `$row_acct[0]['client']` may possibly exist.

Just because your query logic may guarantee zero or one row in the result set, doesn't mean that pdo will return a flat row for you.

Furthermore, you never declare `$client` outside of your conditionally executed loop, so it is no surprise that php is barking about the undeclared variable.

So let's restart from the beginning.

1. Always use ALL CAPS when writing mysql keywords/functions.
2. Prepared statements are useless overhead unless you are binding values to placeholders. In fact, your query is potentially unstable/insecure because you are writing your variable directly into the sql.
3. Use [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to access a single row of the result set.  If the result set is empty, the returned value will be `false`.

Suggested Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT client
        FROM app_reports.user_map 
        WHERE user_name = ?";
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$username]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) { // no row = false
    $_SESSION['client'] = $row['client'];
}
```